# Dataclass dependency injection raises exception with an empty list

Tags: python

I have a basic dataclass, that I want to inject into a bigger class. Without the dependency injection, my dataclass works as expected:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import NamedTuple, List


@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str
    start_url: str
    saved_urls: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

google = Data("Google", "https://www.google.com")
print(google)

# returns Data(name='Google', start_url='https://www.google.com', saved_urls=[])
```

When I pass Data into a Crawl class, it throws an exception expecting saved_urls to be provided during initialisation (I think)?

How do I inject Data into the Crawl class

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import NamedTuple, List


@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str
    start_url: str
    saved_urls: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)


class Crawl(Data):
    def __init__(self, name, start_url, saved_urls):
        self.name = name
        self.start_url = start_url
        self.saved_urls = saved_urls


def main():
    google = Crawl("Google", "https://www.google.com")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# raises TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'saved_urls'
```

For posterity here is the answer provided by Anentropic

```
@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str
    start_url: str
    saved_urls: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

class Crawl(Data):
    def __init__(self, name, start_url):
        super().__init__(name, start_url)

def main():    
    google = Crawl("Google", "https://www.google.com")
    print(google)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# returns Data(name='Google', start_url='https://www.google.com', saved_urls=[])
```

Comment: you need to call `super().__init__(name, start_url, saved_urls)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super  ... but if that's all you're trying to do you don't even need to define an `__init__` method on the subclass

Comment: Python itself doesn't do dependency injection. When you call `Crawl`, you need to provide an explicit list. If you want to perform automatic dependency injection, you'll need a 3rd-party library.

Comment: `Crawl` initialization expects 3 arguments: `name`, `start_url` and `saved_urls`. You provided 2. I think the error is very understandable. The default argument for `saved_urls` is irrelevant, you are still short of one argument in `__init__`.

Comment: Dependency injection wouldn't be implemented using inheritance like this, in any case.

Comment: @Anentropic perfect, thank you for sharing the documentation and solution, it worked exactly how I expected.

Comment: @dimButTries no prob, I think this line `google = Data("Google", "https://www.google.com")` should be `google = Crawl("Google", "https://www.google.com")` ?